# Reading a file for specific word is not working as intended

Tags: ruby

I have a file where I save an id of a post of a page that I'm doing requests to and to avoid duplicates in each request I'm saving the post Id to the file and if the id is there I just want the `.each` loop to break. So far I've been using these methods with a regexp to be more specific, I was just using `.grep("/#{post[:id]}/").size > 0` and the same one but without `.size > 0` and they were not working.

Also used `IO.readlines` < That's what I'm using right now.

`if File.readlines('id_check.txt').grep("/\b#{post[:id]}\b/")` and

`if File.readlines('id_check.txt').grep("/\b#{post[:id]}\b/").size > 0` are not working.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
# CHECK IF POST ID IS IN TEXT FILE TO AVOID DUPLICATES
  if IO.readlines('id_check.txt').grep("/\b#{post[:id]}\b/").size > 0
    puts 'Photo already posted'
    break
  end

  # WRITES ID OF POST IN TEXT FILE
  File.open('id_check.txt', 'a') do |f|
    f.write("#{post[:id]}\n")
  end

  # DOWNLOADS IMAGE
  encapsulated_time = Time.now
  agent.get(post[:preview][:images][0][:source][:url]).save("img/#{encapsulated_time}.jpg")
  puts encapsulated_time
```

Comment: Please give an example of the text in `id_check.txt`.

Comment: @cdarke it's just a string with the post id... It can be something like: "5tlyi2", "5ta4t2" without quotes, each on newlines.